# Making nested list of consecutive numbers in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Can anyone check whether this is a complete BS of a code or not. Obviously it doesn't work because I'm getting false as answer but I just wanna know if this is on the right track or just totally NOT it. Btw I've never programmed on prolog before, I am just learning the basics.

```pl
nested([], []).
nested([H1], [[H1]])
nested([H1,H2|T], [Out]) :- 
    H2 - H1 is 1, 
    nested([H2|T], [[H1|Out]]);
    nested([H2|T], [H1|Out]).
```

Comment: Please show with an example how you want to call this code and what result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

To test equality use `=:=/2` (predicate [`is/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) should be used with **unbound** left operand). Also, always use parentheses around disjunctions (`;/2`) and put them in evidence. So your code can be fixed as follows:

```
% nested(+List, -Nested)
 
  nested([], []).
  nested([X], [[X]]).
  nested([X1,X2|Xs], Out) :-
     X1 + 1 =:= X2,
     (   Out = [[X1|Ys]]
     ;   Out = [ X1|Ys ] ),
     nested([X2|Xs], Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- nested([1,2,3], N).
N = [[1, [2, [3]]]] ;
N = [[1, 2, [3]]] ;
N = [1, [2, [3]]] ;
N = [1, 2, [3]] ;
false.
```

To avoid unpacking/packing each list element twice, and provides **determinism** on the last answer, change your code as follows:

```
% nested(+List, -Nested)

  nested([], []).
  nested([X1|Xs], Out) :-     % unpack first element
      nested(Xs, X1, Out).

  nested([], X1, [[X1]]).
  nested([X2|Xs], X1, Out) :- % unpack second element
      X1 + 1 =:= X2,
      (   Out = [[X1|Ys]]
      ;   Out = [ X1|Ys ] ),
      nested(Xs, X2, Ys).     % no need to pack
```

Example:

```
?- nested([1,2,3], N).
N = [[1, [2, [3]]]] ;
N = [[1, 2, [3]]] ;
N = [1, [2, [3]]] ;
N = [1, 2, [3]].
```

Comment: Your result lists are nested in a weird way....

Comment: @TA_intern I only fixed errors related to the use of the Prolog language, assuming the OP knows how he wants to nest his own lists. If this is not the case, he can post another question.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs narrowing down.

I would suggest looking at [Peano arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+successor-arithmetics), which has useful relational properties. As a simple case:

```
consecutive_peano_list([H|T]) :-
    consecutive_peano_list_(T, H).

consecutive_peano_list_([], _).
consecutive_peano_list_([H|T], P) :-
    H = s(P),
    consecutive_peano_list_(T, H).
```

This then creates an elegant list of successors, without caring about the starting point in the first element:

```
?- consecutive_peano_list(L).
L = [_] ;
L = [_A, s(_A)] ;
L = [_A, s(_A), s(s(_A))] ;
L = [_A, s(_A), s(s(_A)), s(s(s(_A)))] ;
```